# Live output from a batch file with Python

Tags: python, batch-file, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the output from a batch file LIVE as it runs. I would prefer the console of the batch file to also show as it runs. I have tried using `os.popen` and `subprocess.Popen` but the problem is that it does not run the program LIVE in the background and constantly show what is being printed to the console.

Exactly what I want, is to have a string that is constantly updated with the data from the console of the running batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use `os.system`?

Comment: That runs the batch file exactly how I want, but does not give me the console output.